# How to prevent the symbol "&" from being replaced by "&amp;" in the URL?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, developer-console, developer

```
string redirectURL= URL+'OppId='+oppId+'&Country='+country+'&Lang='+lanag+'&Status=Approved&QuoteId='+quoteId;
```

As mentioned above is URL is used for a certain function. But when the URL redirects the character changes from '`&`' to '`&amp;`' automatically.

And this is creating a problem for me. It is showing the error code 404 page can't be found. With '&' character the page is working fine.

How to resolve the issue? How do I restrict the characters from changing?

Please find the below code for your reference.

**In the helper Class**:

```
public static string getQuoteEditUrl(String oppId,String quoteId){
string lanag=CommonUtility.userLanguageCode;
string country = CommonUtility.userCountryCode;
End_Point_Urls__c endPointUrl =new End_Point_Urls__c();
endPointUrl= End_Point_Urls__c.getInstance('Edit_URL');
string URL=endPointUrl.Domain_URL__c;
string redirectURL= URL+'OppId='+oppId+'&Country='+country+'&Lang='+lanag+'&Status=Approved&Quo
eId='+quoteId;
return redirectURL;
}
```

**In Page controller class**

```
public pagereference editQuoteView(){
...
string SelectedDOCNum = Qid; /*Qid is the quote number selected by the user*/
string Opp_ID =oppty.Opportunity_ID__c;
IFrameURL=HelperUtil.getQuoteEditUrl(Opp_ID,SelectedDOCNum);
shouldRedirect=true; 
...
}
```

**In VFpage**

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!editQuoteView}" status="syncing" name="CalloppWebService_JS" />

**URL what I am expecting**:
"https://xyz-q2.abc.com/xyzABC/ABCServiceQuote/edit/quote/?OppId=OPE-00096589212&Country=AU&Lang=en&Status=Approved&QuoteId=0000087752".
```

But every time it redirects the '&' changes to 'amp;'

I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you check if there is some code which encodes this string before the redirection functionality?

Comment: This encoding is due to the way in which the redirectURL is subsequently used/rendered. Can you please [edit] the question to explain how that URL is used, providing the code that uses the URL (or returns it, or inserts it into a page)? I see the visualforce tag, so I'm guessing you've included this into a page? The contextual code is what's important here, not the URL construction itself.

Comment: Hi, @PhilW,

Thanks for your reply.

Could you please check my question again. I have modified the question.

Comment: Hi @arut,

Thanks for your reply.

Could you please check my question again. I have modified the question.

Comment: Could you please include the part(s) of the "compiled" VF page source (the HTML and JavaScript sent to the browser) that relate to the editQuoteView action function? I'm trying to work out what is causing the encoding - seems likely it is the action function infrastructure.

Comment: @PhilW,
Thanks for your comment.
Actually, In the VF page, there was a JS where the HTMLENCODE was mentioned, and due to that reason the character was getting encoded.

Comment: That would certainly cause this sort of thing; that's why I asked about how the URL was used/inserted into the page.